# Print a gantt chart in MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, gantt-chart

Does anyone have a tip, a third-party component or anything else that would help me print a gantt chart created in MOSS 2007. When I try to print it, IE only prints part of the web page, but not all the Gantt chart.

Thanks for your help !

Raphaël

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work as this fix is for allowing printing with Page Viewer Web Part, but try adding the following to a custom css file or include on a Content Editor Web Part.

```
@media print
{
.ms-leftareacell{
display:block;
}
.ms-rightareacell, .ms-titleareaframe{
display:none;
}
.ms-nav{
display:none;
width:0px;
}
.ms-bodyareacell{
left:0px;
margin-left:0px;
float:none;
width:100%;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't do it ! Thanks for your help tought !